# ReactJS Build Error - cannot read property

Tags: reactjs, build

[image: When running 'npm run build']

But inside my project folders theres not name called 'then'

Comment: Run `nmp run build -- --verbose` to get more details

Comment: Creating an optimized production build...ad:flatten Completed in 3ms
Failed to compile..] | : timing config:load:flatten Completed in 3ms

Cannot read property 'then' of undefined


npm timing command:run-script Completed in 171067ms
npm verb exit 1
npm timing npm Completed in 171801ms
npm verb code 1

Comment: it doesnt give any place also

Comment: Okay then, does it throw an error on `npm run start`?

Comment: no its working perfectly

Comment: Are you sure that there is no error in the dev console?

Comment: yes theres no error coming at console